# .htacces can block ip in hosting x but not block in hosting y

Tags: php, apache

in my .htacces I'm trying to block all ip except my ip

like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <myip>
```

this success block all ip except my ip in hosting idhost***
but when I'm trying upload my project in other hosting indo***
it's not block ip anything
how can i'm block all ip except my ip like hosting idhost*** in hosting indo***?

Comment: Make sure usage of .htaccess and it's sub features is enabled for your hosting provider.